# flutter firebaseをつかってログイン機能をつけたがビルド時にエラーが出てしまいます。

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart

FirebaseAuthでのログイン機能実装した時のビルドエラー

[image]

ログイン画面のコード（signup.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'login_page.dart';
import 'signup_model.dart';

class SignupPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final mailController = TextEditingController();
    final passwordController = TextEditingController();

    return ChangeNotifierProvider<SignUpModel>(
      create: (_) => SignUpModel(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Consumer<SignUpModel>(
          builder: (context, model, child) {
            return SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Create Account,",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 26, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 6,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Sign up to get started!",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, color: Colors.grey.shade400),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          controller: mailController,
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            model.mail = text;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Email ID",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: passwordController,
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            model.password = text;
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Password",
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14,
                                color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              borderSide:
                                  BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.auto,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 50,
                          child: FlatButton(
                            color: Colors.yellow[700],
                            onPressed: () async {
                              try {
                                await model.signUp();

                              } catch (e) {
                              }
                            },
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                            ),
                            child: Ink(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                              child: Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                    minHeight: 50, maxWidth: double.infinity),
                                child: Text(
                                  "Sign up",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 16,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            "すでにアカウントをお持ちですか？",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "login",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Color(0xFF3b5999),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

モデルページ（signup_model.dart）

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  String mail = '';
  String password = '';

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future signUp() async {
    if (mail.isEmpty) {
      throw ('メールアドレスを入力してください');
    }

    if (password.isEmpty) {
      throw ('パスワードを入力してください');
    }

    // todo
    final User user = (await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: mail,
      password: password,
    ))
        .user!;
    final email = user.email;

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').add(
      {
        'email': email,
        'createdAt': Timestamp.now(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

アプリ起動時に Firebase.initialize; はされていますか？？
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}

/// We are using a StatefulWidget such that we only create the [Future] once,
/// no matter how many times our widget rebuild.
/// If we used a [StatelessWidget], in the event where [App] is rebuilt, that
/// would re-initialize FlutterFire and make our application re-enter loading state,
/// which is undesired.
class App extends StatefulWidget {
  // Create the initialization Future outside of `build`:
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  /// The future is part of the state of our widget. We should not call `initializeApp`
  /// directly inside [build].
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      // Initialize FlutterFire:
      future: _initialization,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Check for errors
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return SomethingWentWrong();
        }

        // Once complete, show your application
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return MyAwesomeApp();
        }

        // Otherwise, show something whilst waiting for initialization to complete
        return Loading();
      },
    );
  }
}
```